# procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

can any one please help me to write a procedure for

mysql function or procedure
 where the input will be a schema name
 you need to read all the list of tables in the scheme using meta data
 and for each table where you have a column "PRS_DATE",
 delete the rows that are 30 days old
 based on this "PRS_DATE" column value.

Comment: Here we go start with this..... CREATE PROCEDURE purge_tables (IN myschema VARCHAR(100))

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
create procedure delete_data(schemata varchar(25))
Begin
DECLARE  tab_name varchar(64);
DECLARE  done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE table_name_cur  cursor for select table_name from information_schema.TABLES where table_schema=schemata;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;


  OPEN  table_name_cur;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH  table_name_cur INTO tab_name;

    IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
   --     delete from tab_name where  PRS_DATE <  now() - interval 1 month;

set @x =concat('delete from ', tab_name,' where ','PRS_DATE \< ', 'now() - interval 1 month'); 
   select @x;    
    prepare stmt2 from @x;
        execute stmt2;
    deallocate prepare stmt2; 

    END LOOP;
  CLOSE table_name_cur;
END //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: If this is your solution to your own question, please edit it to include a sentence that indicates that. I edited your code for formatting (indenting 4 spaces to the right)