# creating a stored procedure to delete rows from a date column older than 30 days from all tables in my database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [procedure in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767588/procedure-in-mysql)

can some one please help me 
iam new to mysql
creating a stored procedure to delete rows from a date column older than 30 days from all tables in my database in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.MyDate < SUBDATE(@NOW, 30)
```

Comment: here i can delete only from a single table, but i have to do this process for all the tables in my database in which the column name is prs_date

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
create procedure delete_data(schemata varchar(25))
Begin
DECLARE  tab_name varchar(64);
DECLARE  done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE table_name_cur  cursor for select table_name from information_schema.TABLES where table_schema=schemata;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;


  OPEN  table_name_cur;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH  table_name_cur INTO tab_name;

    IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
   --     delete from tab_name where  PRS_DATE <  now() - interval 1 month;

set @x =concat('delete from ', tab_name,' where ','PRS_DATE \< ', 'now() - interval 1 month'); 
   select @x;    
    prepare stmt2 from @x;
        execute stmt2;
    deallocate prepare stmt2; 

    END LOOP;
  CLOSE table_name_cur;
END //
delimiter ;
```